# Java JPA Mysql error in code:The state field path cannot be resolved to a valid type

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem, i can't figure out which is the problem with the code.
I'm new in Japa Jpa projects and i can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

This is the error i'm getting. it's longer, but i hope this is enough.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT item FROM NewsArticle item WHERE item.user.idUser = '0']. 
[40, 56] The state field path 'item.user.idUser' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1743)
```

The line with the problem:

```
 Query getFeed = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT item FROM NewsArticle item WHERE item.user.idUser = \'" + loggedUser.getIduser() + "\'");
```

And the class generated with generate entities from tables:

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the news_articles database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="news_articles")
@NamedQuery(name="NewsArticle.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM NewsArticle n")
public class NewsArticle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int idnews;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

    private String description;

    private String source;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Comment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="newsArticle")
    private List<Comment> comments;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Category
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="news_category"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="idNews_nc")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="idCategory_nc")
            }
        )
    private List<Category> categories;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userID")
    private User user;

    public NewsArticle() {
    }

    public int getIdnews() {
        return this.idnews;
    }

    public void setIdnews(int idnews) {
        this.idnews = idnews;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return this.source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return this.comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public Comment addComment(Comment comment) {
        getComments().add(comment);
        comment.setNewsArticle(this);

        return comment;
    }

    public Comment removeComment(Comment comment) {
        getComments().remove(comment);
        comment.setNewsArticle(null);

        return comment;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return this.categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Comment: "item.user" exists since you show it in your class. You don't show the "User" class, so people have no idea whether that field ("idUser") exists in that class. You could also try doing an EXPLICIT join to User for more control over joining

Answer (score 1):

You define the `id` as an `int` :

```
@Id
private int idnews;
```

and then in the query you put it between two quotes?!

```
item.user.idUser = \'" + loggedUser.getIduser() + "\'"
//------------------^-------------------------------^
```

This is what make the problem, so to solve it just remove the quotes

---

**Important**

beside avoid concatination in the query it is not secure, instead you can use `setParameter` like :

```
Query getFeed = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT item FROM NewsArticle item WHERE item.user.idUser = :id");
getFeer.setParameter("id", loggedUser.getIduser());
```